# List of SAS dataset names

Tags: sas

I used to ran simple command then copy the results tab (paste to excel file).

```
proc datasets lib=cut;
RUN;
```

However, it is not working now:

- [image: This will pop up]
- Disregard selected Yes or No, I will get this error:
  [image]

I figured maybe because there were too many records?
The library has 54000+ tables now (and growing).

Question:

1. Is there a simple way output the result directly to a dataset?
2. Can I add a filter in proc datasets codes? (such as where)

Comment: Use ODS EXCEL to create an Excel file directly.  No need to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `proc sql` for this.

```
proc sql;
create table table_list as
select *
from dictionary.tables
where libname='CUT';
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you are producing too large of a printed report for the Enterprise Guide front end to return from SAS to your PC where you are running EG.  But it sounds like don't actually want to produce the report at all so don't ask for the report.

Getting the contents of datasets is what PROC CONTENTS is for.  It has an option to generate a dataset and also an option to suppress the printed report.

```
proc contents data=cut._all_ noprint out=contents; run;
```

This will get one observation per variable.

If you just want the member names then you can subset it.  Perhaps using NODUPKEY.

```
proc sort data=contents out=members nodupkey ;
   by memname ;
run;
```

Or just keep the observations where VARNUM=1 so that you get only one observation per member.

Answer (score 1):

Metadata on the library tables are stored in two primary tables:

1. dictionary.tables/sashelp.vtable

This contains information on the tables, such as the number of variables, observations, sort, index, labels etc.

2. dictionary.column/sashelp.vcolumn

This contains information on each table in more detail, including each variable, variable type, length, label, format etc.

These are views available in SAS and can be access the same as any other data set. Note that libnames are stored capitalized and cases must match.

```
   data datasets_in_cut_lib;
     set sashelp.vtable;
     where libname = 'CUT';
   run;
```

You can also pipe your output straight to Excel using ODS Excel, if the output goes to a result window (not log). The last sheet (Sheet 6) should have what you want.

```
ods excel file='/home/userID/example.xlsx';
  proc datasets lib=cut;
  run;quit;
ods excel close;
```